# How to prevent the default value '0' from being shown in Struts2 textfield tag

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a form with several textfields. When I populate it with data, there are some integer textfields which is showing '0', which is the default value for integer. I want the textfield to be blank than a zero.

```
<s:textfield id="txtPhone" name="phone"/>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Integer` class and not `int` for that. int will always be initialized to 0.
S2 OGNL and type convertor will take care of type conversion for you.

For Integer default will be null and it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the field is really optional, make the field Integer, so the default will be null!